# Manipulating functions in python

Tags: python, function, equation, algebra

I want to be able to use one function in another function, in this case the function nu in the expression for integrand. At the moment this is my code:

```
from trapezium import trap
import scipy as sp

# mass_enc returns the mass enclosed within a radius R
# nu is the density function

def mass_enc(q, R):
    integrand = lambda r: 4 * sp.pi * r**2 * q(r)
    return trap(integrand, 0, R, 100)

def nu(a):
    return a

print(mass_enc(nu, 10))
```

However this seems messy - is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you want the `q` function to be the integrand, as opposed to the lambda? where does `r` come from?

Comment: Your code is fine as it is: it's not that messy. If you wanted to, you could replace the `integrand = lambda r : ...` expression with a function definition: `def integrand(r): return 4 * pi * r**2 * q(r)`.